# Can I make my user input accept either int or string values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

I was wondering if it was possible to make my input accept *either* `int` or `str` values. This is the code so far:

```py
NumOfKeys = int(input("How many keys would you like to add:"))

for i in range(NumOfKeys):
    TypeInput = input("Is your key:value a string or int value? (str/int/both)")
    if TypeInput.lower() == "str":
        KeyInput = input("Please input your key")
        ValueInput = input("Please input your value")
    elif TypeInput.lower() == "int":
        KeyInput = int(input("Please input your key"))
        ValueInput = int(input("Please input your value"))
    elif TypeInput.lower() == "both":
        # I want the key to be either str or int
        # I want the value to be either str or int`
```

Comment: What kind of inputs you recieve(Names, Dates, etc...)? Which values are a valid strings in  your program? Its will help us understand better your problem

Comment: I'm trying to make an input that gives the keys and values to an empty dictionary, and I want the input to accept either int or string values.

Comment: The inputs receive data such as age, budget, name, etc...

Comment: if the format of the input is like this: name space number you can split the string the the input get. and get 2 diffirent variables and cast the number to int

Comment: How does that work?

Comment: ```data = input().split(' ')``` and it return a list of 2 variable. can you show me the code of the input you had and ill improve it

Comment: I've edited the message and put my entire code

Comment: What does .split() do?

Comment: After i see your code i realize you dont need it. but this method split the string when he see a specific char

Comment: if i have ```a="a b"``` so ```a..split(' ')``` will return this list: ```['a','b']```

Comment: Now i understand better you questions. like i answerd bellow, if the input contain both characters and digits or only characters its should be a string. integers cant contain characters. i checked if the input contain only digits with the method ```isdigit()```. this method return ```True``` if the string contain only digits and can be casted to an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NumOfKeys = int(input("How many keys would you like to add:"))
for i in range(NumOfKeys):
    KeyInput = input("Please insert your key")
    if KeyInput.isdigit():
        TypeInput = int(KeyInput)
    ValueInput =input("Please input your value")
    if ValueInput.isdigit():
        ValueInput = int(ValueInput)
```

Hope is what you intend. Let me know if its ok.
If the key contain both number and characters is must be a string.

Answer (score 0):

An input in python will return a string.
After storing you input in a variable you can than try to parse it into an int with the int() function if you need it but it will be stored as a string first.

Answer (score 0):

I am practicing python at the time I got this idea. It's really helpful for beginners.

Try this:

```py
first_number=(input("Enter the first number: "))
    
second_number=(input("Enter the second number: "))
    
    
if first_number.isdigit() and second_number.isdigit():
    
    conversion_first=int(first_number)
    conversion_second=int(second_number)
    print(conversion_first*conversion_second)
    
elif(first_number.isdigit() !=True ):
    print(f"Enter the first number correctly '''{first_number}''' !!! that is not a string type, should enter number only: ")
    
elif(second_number.isdigit()!=True):
    print(f"Enter the second number '''{second_number}''' !!! should be number only")
    
else:
    print("No...it is not a number")
```