# What is wrong in this Python code, can anyone share me the correct code?

Tags: python-3.x

When I tried to give the String Values, it was throwing the error.

My Code from Python3:

a,b,c = [eval(x) for x in input("Enter the Values:").split(,)]

print(a,b,c,sep=':')

Comment: How it will work if I use both String and Integer.

Comment: It uses `eval`, that’s nearly always wrong.

Comment: So basically, I have to use different function to input Str and Int, correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I make my user input accept either int or string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66731704/can-i-make-my-user-input-accept-either-int-or-string-values)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `eval()` on input,

try:

```
a,b,c = [x for x in input("Enter the Values: ").split(",")]
print(a,b,c,sep=':')
```

Comment: I tried, it is throwing the below error


  File "main.py", line 1
    a,b,c = [x for x in input("Enter the Values: ").split(",")]
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: yes there was an extra indentation which I fixed now.

Comment: Many Thanks, It worked for string. 

But one last question is, but how it will work if I use both String and Integer.

Comment: That is a new question, you need to make a well-defined question and show what you have done and what is your expected answer. For now, if this answer has resolved your first issue, please accept by pressing the tick on my answer.

Comment: Done. Thanks. I'm new here

Comment: Requesting you to help me with my last ask, 

How it will work if I use both String and Integer.

Answer (score -1):

a,b,c = [eval(x) for x in input("Enter the Values:").split(",")]

print(a,b,c,sep=':')

My **Expectation** was to input: String, Integer, Float for a,b,c respectively.

**Error** : File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'XYZ' is not defined

---

Finally, I found the answer to this problem. We can use eval for int and String datatype.

However, while inputting it, you need to Enclose the String datatype in single/double quotes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).